# How do I add mappings to ElasticSearch grails plugin?

Tags: grails, groovy, elasticsearch

I am trying to add a parent mapping to elasticSearch. I'm using the [grails plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/elasticsearch).

[Here is an example of the mapping I want to add](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/parent-field.html)

I'm struggling to find where to put this.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: the elasticsearch-grails plugin is quite basic implementation. At most it only supports [core types](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html) of elasticsearch. And for the fields, it only supports _boost, _index & _analyzer as of now. source - [line 28](https://github.com/mstein/elasticsearch-grails-plugin/blob/master/src/java/org/grails/plugins/elasticsearch/mapping/SearchableClassPropertyMapping.java)